# group option items javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a multiple select which contains options

```
<select id="cart" name="cart" multiple>
    <option price="4.00" name="Green Beans">
    <option price="4.00" name="Green Beans">
    <option price="4.00" name="Green Beans">
    <option price="6.00" name="Blue Beans">
    <option price="7.00" name="Black Beans">
    <option price="7.00" name="Black Beans">
</select>
```

I want to group them using javascript so I can obtain

```
<select id="cart" name="cart" multiple>
    <option price="4.00" name="3x Green Beans">
    <option price="6.00" name="1x Blue Beans">
    <option price="7.00" name="2x Black Beans">
</select>
```

Comment: what did you try so far ?

Comment: What is the source of your data?  Are you receive html?

Comment: Why do you need a `name` on `<option>`?

Comment: When should the grouping occur? By event or initially?

Comment: the grouping should occur when i click a button

Comment: Well, first `price` is not valid HTML and, in a `select`, `option` elements must be closed with a default value as their content.

Answer (score 0):

My idea: Getting all options tags, then using `while` loop to check until the tags array doesn't have any item.

Inside the loop, we try to compare `price` attribute in the first item of the array with the `price` attribute of the others. After getting, push them to the `result` array.

Then, we use the new loop to update the `name` attribute to the specific tag and delete the duplicate(s).

You can use `F12` to check html code in the result.

Result:

```c#
<select id="cart" name="cart" multiple="">
  <option price="4.00" name="3x Green Beans">Item 1</option>
  <option price="6.00" name="1x Blue Beans">Item 4</option>
  <option price="7.00" name="2x Black Beans">Item 5</option>
</select>
```

```js
var options = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('option'));

var result = [];

while (options.length) {
  var price = options[0].getAttribute('price');

  var items = options.filter(x => x.getAttribute('price') === price);
  
  items.forEach(x => options.splice(options.findIndex(e => e.getAttribute('price') === x.getAttribute('price')),1));
  
  result.push(items);
}

for (var items of result) {
  var price = items[0].getAttribute('price');
  
  var prices = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(`[price='${price}']`));
  
  var name = prices[0].getAttribute('name');
  
  prices[0].setAttribute('name', `${prices.length}x ${name}`);
  
  var temp = prices.filter((x, y) => y);
  
  temp.forEach(x => x.remove());
}
```

```html
<select id="cart" name="cart" multiple>
  <option price="4.00" name="Green Beans">Item 1
  <option price="4.00" name="Green Beans">Item 2
  <option price="4.00" name="Green Beans">Item 3
  <option price="6.00" name="Blue Beans">Item 4
  <option price="7.00" name="Black Beans">Item 5
  <option price="7.00" name="Black Beans">Item 6
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

See comments inline below, but be warned that your existing HTML is invalid because there is no such attribute as `price` and with a `select`, you should have closing `option` tags and the `option` elements should contain the default text to display.

```js
// Convert initial options to an array
let input = 
  Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("#cart > option"));
  
let output = []; // Prepare final array

// Loop over initial array
input.forEach(function(item, pos) {
    let sItem = item.outerHTML; // Convert DOM element to string
    
    // If output array doesn't contain input string...
    if(output.indexOf(sItem) == -1){
      output.push(sItem);  // Add it to the output array
    }
});

// Replace the select with the output
document.getElementById("cart").innerHTML = output.join("");
```

```html
<select id="cart" name="cart" multiple>
  <option value="4.00">Green Beans</option>
  <option value="4.00">Green Beans</option>
  <option value="4.00">Green Beans</option>
  <option value="6.00">Blue Beans</option>
  <option value="7.00">Black Beans</option>
  <option value="7.00">Black Beans</option>
</select>
```